# Spinnaker for CD

Tags: spinnaker, amazon-eks

I was planning to use Jenkins(CI) ----> Spinnaker(CD) integration for AWS EKS.
Does Spinnaker support multi-cluster deployments?

For example:

I will have 4 clusters in different accounts
and I want to have 1 Spinnaker deployed to one of the clusters and manage other 3 as well.

is it possible to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes is possible. The suggested way is to have Spinnaker Running in an AWS Account called Spinnaker or CD and in a specific namespace called spin.

A great guide to follow for Spinnaker in EKS is [Continuous Delivery using Spinnaker on Amazon EKS](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/opensource/continuous-delivery-spinnaker-amazon-eks/)